# Jasmine - Unable to append element to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am testing an Ionic app using Jasmine and Karma. I am trying to append the following `div` element to the DOM, but `nav` is returning undefined. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

```
 div = '<div class="tab-nav"></div>';
 appending = $('body').append(div);

 nav = $('.tab-nav');
 console.log(nav);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just add text, you have to add a DOM element (which needs to be created first)

```
div = $('<div/>').addClass('tab-nav');
appending = $('body').append(div);
```